# Pull Down Table View Cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drop-down-menu, uitableview

I am trying to create a feature similar to the Facebook android app where on the home screen, if you pull down , it starts updating and a new cell is added to the top with the title "Updating..." :[image] And then it disappears once I scroll down (Until the next time I pull the table down).

The view I am trying to achieve is something similar but on a UITableView.
I wish to add a Pull Down menu at the top, which looks like this when open :

[image]

And when I scroll up It moves up (closes) along the table as if a Table Cell and looks like this :

[image]

But it always stays on top. Like a Table Section Header. And if I scroll to the top of the UITableView , it comes down again as if a UITableCell at table cell index:0.
How can I achieve this ? I tried PullableView Fabio Rodella, but I dont think it can be implemented on a UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out Raywenderlich tutorial. [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22174/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-33)

U need to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6.0 and later, you can use UIRefreshControl on a UITableView
[Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)